# Schedule A Local Notification In watchOS2

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, uilocalnotification, apple-watch

I was wondering whether it is possible to create a schedule a local notification from the watch without communicating with the paired iOS phone via WCSession. If so how does one go about scheduling the notification? I create the notification but then don't know how to schedule it on the device/present it automatically?

```
UILocalNotification *theNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
[theNotification setAlertBody:@"This is a test"];
[theNotification setAlertTitle:@"Test"];
...???
```

Thanks